# Eclipse "Install new Software" option

Tags: eclipse

I am new in the Eclipse, I am facing a problem:

> Install new Software option not showing in my eclipse.

Eclipse version: 8.5

Comment: Actually I want to install Android into the eclipse so that I need to "Help -> Install new Software option " but its now showing.

Comment: It's now showing? Or not showing? Can you give more details on the problem, of it it's resolved, just answer it yourself so that it's not just left open?

Comment: Hi Francis, Thanks for your comment, Still the option not showing, I have install the android SDK, and now I want to plug it into eclipse, I am working on it, but now I have to enter android URL into "Help -> Install new Software". But this option not showing in my Eclipse 8.5. I don't know what is the problem, I have searched hard into the web but I didn't find any answer. so please suggest me the how can I plug it into the eclipse. I am using the following vidio "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIL1UouA4dE"...

Comment: There is no 8.5 version of Eclipse, so maybe you are not even running Eclipse. Can you provide a screenshot? Make sure you are actually starting Eclipse correctly.

Comment: Hi, I am using MyEclipse 8.5 ..

Comment: Same issue here, using Eclipse 4.3: http://imgur.com/RHmyJgo
Edit: For clarity, it was there and now it disappeared after I installed photran for some reason. No idea how to get it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need you need to use Help -> MyEclipse Configuration Center as [described here](http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-10278.html). The update mechanism for MyEclipse is accessed in a different way than standard Eclipse.

Comment: I know this is an old question/answer but I have this same problem and have not been able to find an answer anywhere on the internet. I AM using Eclipse (technically QNX Momentics 5.00) and the Install New Software option disappeared from my help menu a little over a month ago. I have no idea why or how to get it back. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For those struggling, I found a good workaround on another site:

Go to help -> search and type 'install new' and select the search result that comes up - then you can proceed with installs as normal.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the configuration is screwed up.
You just need to remove the "eclipse" directory in C:/Users// folder, then start it again. I came across the problem with an IDE based on eclipse, so I'm not sure the directory containing the configuration is "eclipse" here.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same question. I just copy another eclipse to where  eclipse installed(in my computer is /usr/lib/), and it becomes normal.

Answer (score 0):

Adding 3 pre-conditions for the answers above along with few other workarounds :

1. Your eclipse may have re-opened when you switched workspace , this may be the reason why you are not seeing option anymore . This happens when you are not admin on the machine.

> Close eclipse and click icon to open again

2. Check if you are an admin . If yes , follow steps below :

> ```
>  Go to Help/Search
>  Search for "Install new"
>  Select "Updating and installing software" from the local search results.
>  Click on the link by the name "Installing new software"
>  Here click the first link with the text "Help  Install New Software ..."
> ```

3. If you work somewhere , where you are not admin on the machine , last step in solution above will not work.
   In such case , follow steps :

> Close eclipse , select eclipse icon and Shift-Enter to open it.